# Android Webview Response Reading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

I am facing problem with reading response from the webview which loads a registration get url. The requirement is as below.

I have to communicate with a user registration servlet which can respond with html and xml content. For initial get request the servlet responds with html content and I can able to show that in WebView using load URL method. In the web view user enters the registration details and clicks submit, the servlet reponds with xml status code and registration details. I have to read this xml response from the servlet that can be obtained from the web view and do action (ex: close the web view and alert user) with respect to the xml response.

**Please get me a solution.
I tried overriding Webview clients onPageFinsihed() and reading data again from the URL by opening an HTTP connection. I think this implementation communicates with the server two times, Is that correct?**

Regards
@nish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually extract HTML from the WebView, this can be done in different ways [this](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/) is one approach.

Comment: No not only html, the server can respond with xml too. So I need all response in my code and I will check if it is html or xml and take necessary action.

Comment: Hi MrWaqasAhmed,  From the URL you mentioned it is calling loadURL again from the onPageFinished() method. In my case this will do two registrations requests to the server. am I correct?

Comment: @anish please post the solution if u hav solved your problem..It would be really helpful if post the solution. Thanks